# Longtable over pagebreak creates duplicate Label

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, longtable, labels, auxiliary-files

I have a weird one. In my latex document, a table is created and in the .aux file, the table is somehow duplicated, which generates a multiple label warning.

I was able to figure out, that it occurred, because that table is separated due to a pagebreak, which is fine in itself, but the multiple label warning ergo creation is annoying.

Infos:

```
Preamble:
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, oneside, english]{scrbook}
\usepackage{ amsmath }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ graphicx }
\usepackage{ microtype }
\usepackage[ english ]{ babel }
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
```

This is my current table command packed in a new environment. When I place the label directly behind the caption, is will be generated twice over a page break. Placing it in the second part of the new environment creates an error.

Where should I place the label command or which other command structure could I use to circumvent that situation?

```
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

% Variable Table Environment
\newenvironment{FancyTable}[4]
    {
        % Before each new major table
        \ra{1.3}
        \begin{longtable}{  @{} #1 @{}}
        % Caption
        \caption{#2} \label{tab:#4}\\
    \\
        % Top Section
        \toprule #3 \\
        % Midsection
        \midrule
        \endhead
    }
    {
        \bottomrule 
        \end{longtable} 
    }
```

Calling the table command

```
\begin{FancyTable}{lrr}{Ditolandia Results}{Size & Results ($1.3$) & Actual}{PPRR}
    $a$     &       $0.1$       &       $0.1$       \\
    $b$     &       $0.1$       &       $0.1$       \\
    $c$     &       $0.1$       &       $0.1$       \\
\end{FancyTable}
```

Aux File extract:

```
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {\relax 3.1}{\ignorespaces Ditolandia Results}}{16}}
\newlabel{tab:PPRR}{{\relax 3.1}{16}}
\gdef \LT@vi {\LT@entry 
    {1}{52.80566pt}\LT@entry 
    {1}{67.80566pt}\LT@entry 
    {1}{35.16675pt}}
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {\relax 3.1}{\ignorespaces Ditolandia Results}}{17}}
\newlabel{tab:PPRR}{{\relax 3.1}{17}}
```

I can live with that warning, but it is annoying.

Comment: Please do not only show code snippets but always a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Without we cannot reproduce the problem and cannot test our suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the definition of `FancyTable` to set the label (and maybe the entry into the list of tables) only on the first page:

```
\newenvironment{FancyTable}[4]
    {
        % Before each new major table
        \ra{1.3}
        \begin{longtable}{  @{} #1 @{}}
        % Caption
        \caption{#2} \label{tab:#4}\\
    \\
        % Top Section
        \toprule #3 \\
        % Midsection
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
         \caption[]{#2}\\
    \\
        % Top Section
        \toprule #3 \\
        % Midsection
        \midrule
        \endhead
   }
    {
        \bottomrule 
        \end{longtable} 
    }
```

See [the `longtable` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) about `\endfirsthead` vs. `\endhead` and `\caption[]{…}` vs. `\caption{…}`.

Comment: I guess, I should have spend some more time in the manual. Thanks